# if date_hierarchy + '__month' in request.GET not working

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

i'm making this code in admin.py:

```
def get_next_in_date_hierarchy(request, date_hierarchy):
if date_hierarchy + '__day' in request.GET:
    return 'hour'

if date_hierarchy + '__month' in request.GET:
    return 'day'

if date_hierarchy + '__year' in request.GET:
    return 'week'

return 'month'

def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
    period = get_next_in_date_hierarchy(request, self.date_hierarchy)
        response.context_data['period'] = period
        summary_over_time = qs.annotate(
            period=Trunc(
            'installation_date',
            period,
            output_field=DateTimeField(),
        ),
       ).values('period').annotate(total=Count('id')).order_by('period')
```

to return the filter specific in admin but not working because `'__day'` not exists in request

my models:

```
contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, verbose_name=_('User'),null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
installation_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name=_('Date Installation'),auto_now=True)
session_id = models.CharField(verbose_name=_("Session"), max_length=100, default=None, null=True, blank=None)
```

what can i do to `'__day'` exist in the request

Comment: Show your urls.py. Did you actually checked that `__day` is in request GET params?

Comment: this code is returned to the admin template

Comment: ok, but it's not obvious what's your question is actually about. You are checking that something `date_hierarchy__{day or month or year}` in the request. It's not, so next step is to check two things: urls (maybe your round defined incorrectly) and something that should send this request (maybe it's not sending it properly). Without code listing it's almost impossible to guess.

Comment: I edited this post, sorry

Comment: np, now this - to something be present in request it should be added to the request somewhere. What I recommend to start with first - debug to see what's actually in the request. Next step is to check the method (view) that spawn the request. Sorry, but it's still impossible to guess why something is not in request because there could be anything there - it depends on request producer. You didn't show the logic that produces requests here.